# How to protect authenticated routes using redux-persist react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I'm trying to protect authenticated routes using redux-persist and redux-toolkit in a react native app. I thought this would be as simple as accessing the store or state using a selector to check if my token was empty or not and then conditionally rendering the different screens depending but it just throws two errors: "The above error occurred in the  component:" and ""Uncaught TypeError: config is undefined""

Here's my App.tsx file. I have an auth state that holds a jwt, I'd like to block off the other routes if its empty. I'm not sure how to do this.

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import React from "react";
import HomeScreen from "./src/screens/home";
import Register from "./src/screens/register";
import Feed from "./src/screens/feed";
import Login from "./src/screens/login";
import { Text } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { NativeBaseProvider } from "native-base";
import customTheme from "./src/shared/theme";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { persistor, store } from "./src/store/store";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import ProfileScreen from "./src/screens/Profile";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

//web links
const linking = {
  prefixes: [],
  config: {
    screens: {
      Login: "login",
      Register: "register",
      Profile: "profile",
      Home: "home",
      Feed: "feed",
    },
  },
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <SafeAreaProvider>
          <NativeBaseProvider theme={customTheme}>
            <NavigationContainer
              linking={linking}
              fallback={<Text>Something went wrong...</Text>}
            >
              <Stack.Navigator
                initialRouteName="Login"
                screenOptions={{
                  headerShown: false,
                  animation: "none",
                  gestureEnabled: false,
                }}
              >
                {/* what do I do here: I get an error... */}
                {store.getState().auth.jwt === "" ? (
                  <>
                    <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
                  </>
                ) : (
                  <>
                    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
                  </>
                )}
              </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
          </NativeBaseProvider>
          <StatusBar />
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

I've tried using `store.getState().auth.jwt === ""` but that throws an error "Uncaught TypeError: config is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by moving everything below PersistGate into a new function and used a regular selector there to get my auth token and rendered conditionally like I was doing.

Also conditionally declared the initialRouteName.